# Access DB one ID, multiple classes and associated dates

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm creating a DB for my office.  We have about 200 employees.  Each employee was required to complete at least 1 of 12 courses within 2 years of being hired (so different completion/qualification dates for every course, some people have been here 20 years, some just 1 year) to become qualified.  Some have completed multiple courses.  Each course has to be refreshed periodically (each refresh period is different and based on the last refresher date).  I'm having trouble with the layout of the table.  Here's what I have as an idea, but i'm trying to see if there is a less busy way to lay out the data.  I want to be able to run a query that tells me what person has completed what class (so it would have to look at all 3 class columns).  I also want to be able to tell when their qualification has lapsed, or is coming up.  So far I've created an employee data table that looks like the table below.

```
ID Name    Class1    Class2    Class3  QualDt-Cl1 QualDt-Cl2 QualDt-Cl3  LstRequal1 ...
1  Bob      Art      Spanish           3/17/1989   9/12/2010              3/8/2012
2  Sally    Math                       8/31/2012
3  George   Physics            History 2/6/2005               7/6/1996
4  Casey    History                    6/8/2000 
5  Joe      English  Sports    Physics 12/10/1993  10/15/2001 4/22/2006
```

The classes are listed in their own table and each class column pulls from that.  The qual date refresher will be a calculated column in the query based on the last refresher date.
Is there a way to put all the classes one person is qualified for in one column and have the associated date for requalifiing for each particular cours in another column?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be less confusing if you had a table per subject and register the people's names under each one with the date passed.

Also it would probably help to declutter the table from uneccssary info like the exact date the exam was passed, you can do month and year or maybe just year? if the lee way is 2 years that would probably make more sense - also making the qulified calculation easier.

The query would work if you searched per subject maybe ? or who would qualify to do what subject this current year and then the next.

this is not much of a question that you would ask on here by the way - but hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

When designing a database, any time you find yourself adding columns with names like `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3` you should immediately stop and think about whether it makes more sense to put those columns in a separate child table called `Classes` with a link (relation) to the parent. There are several reasons for this, including:

1. What happens when somebody takes a fourth course? Saying "that will never happen" ignores the fact that "never is a *very* long time" and none of us can predict the future.
2. When checking whether or not someone has taken a course you really need to check `(Class1 IS NULL) OR (Class2 IS NULL) OR (Class3 IS NULL)` and that can get *really* tedious, It also means that if you *do* have to add `Class4` then all of that SQL code has to be corrected.
3. Similarly, if you want to find someone who took "CPR" you'd have to look for people with  `(Class1 = 'CPR') OR (Class2 = 'CPR') OR (Class3 = 'CPR')`. Yuck.

So, save yourself some trouble (a lot of trouble, really) and create a `Classes` table:

```
ID
ClassName
QualDate
(etc. )
```

...where `ID` is the ID number from the main table (what is called a "foreign key"). From your sample data, your `Classes` table would look something like this:

```
ID  ClassName   QualDate
1   Art         3/17/1989
1   Spanish     9/12/2010
2   Math        8/31/2012
3   Physics     2/6/2005
3   History     7/6/1996
...
```